# NameError: name 'click_entry' is not defined (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

class fidgetSpinner:    


    def spin():
        status_str = float(click_entry.get())

    window = Tk() # Create a window
    window.title("11.2 GUI")


    mainframe = Frame(window)
    mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
    mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    click_entry = Entry(mainframe, width=20)
    click_entry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

    click = click_entry.get()
    status_str = StringVar()

    Label(mainframe, textvariable=status_str).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))
    Button(mainframe, text="Fidget Click!", command=spin).grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=W)

    Label(mainframe, text="Enter Click Count:").grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=W)
    Label(mainframe, text="status:").grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=E)
    Label(mainframe, text=click).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=E)

    window.mainloop() # Create an event loop

myWidgets = fidgetSpinner() # Create GUI


myWidgets = fidgetSpinner() # Create GUI
```

When I run this program and enter some text and when I input some number into

`click_entry = Entry(mainframe, width=20)` and click `Fidget Click!`

it just says

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/kalib/OneDrive - University of Tasmania/Programming introduction KIT001/11.2dn GUI/11.2dn GUI.py", line 7, in spin
    status_str = float(click_entry.get())
NameError: name 'click_entry' is not defined
```

Also I didn't want to make a program about a fidget spinner that's just what we were meant to call the program.

Comment: Where are you defining `click_entry`? Is it a global in the same module as `fidgetSpinner`? That's the only place it can be if the code you've shown is going to work. Though your class is very weird, since it does all its work statically in the class namespace, not in `__init__` or some other method that gets called for each separate instance.

Comment: i thought i was defining click_entry with this line "click_entry = Entry(mainframe, width=20)". is that not how i'm supposed to do it? i have only been learning python this semester at uni?

Comment: Sorry about that, I missed reading the line where it appeared in the class body. My answer explains why it doesn't work in that place, since methods can't see class variables directly. You might be able make it work by naming the class, or via a reference to an instance (such as `self`), or by getting rid of the class entirely (so `clicked_entry` would be a global, and `spin` would not be a method).

Answer (score 2):

please add an extra line like this it will solve the issue

```
global click_entry # to declare it as a global variable so yoou can access from any where 
click_entry = Entry(mainframe, width=20)
click_entry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))
```

here the click_entry must be a global variable and you are trying to access it out of private variable scope

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
from tkinter import *


class fidgetSpinner:
    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk()
        window.title("11.2 GUI")

        mainframe = Frame(window)
        mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
        mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.click_entry = Entry(mainframe, width=20)
        self.click_entry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

        click = self.click_entry.get()

        status_str = StringVar()

        Label(mainframe, textvariable=status_str).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))
        Button(mainframe, text="Fidget Click!", command=self.spin).grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=W)

        Label(mainframe, text="Enter Click Count:").grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=W)
        Label(mainframe, text="status:").grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=E)
        Label(mainframe, text=click).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=E)

        window.mainloop()

    def spin(self):
        status_str = float(self.click_entry.get())

myWidgets = fidgetSpinner()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because you're putting it within a class body. A function defined in a class is a method, it's usually going to be called on an instance of the class, rather than directly. Your specific problem is caused by the fact that methods do not have access to the class namespace the way functions get access to the global namespace. You can see this in a simpler example:

```
class Foo:
    x = 1
    def foo():
        print(x)
```

If you call `Foo.foo()`, it will give you a error about `x`, since the variable defined with that name in the class is not accessible to the function directly.

This is one reason you should usually define variables you're going to use in your class as attributes of `self`, usually in the `__init__` method. Other methods can use the same attribute notation to get access to the value later:

```
class Foo2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1

    def foo(self): # note, self argument!
        print(self.x)
```

Note however that the code within `Foo` in my first example would have worked if it was moved out of the class entirely. If `x` was a variable in the global namespace, and `foo` was a top-level funciton, there would be no problem. So an alternative to fixing up your class (as [Konstantin's answer does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50270044/1405065) pretty well) is to get rid of the class and just have a bunch of global code. A class might be nicer in the long run, but it's not required, and just writing simple script code may be easier when you're just learning Python and `tkinter`.